# Delete all the previous UITableViewCell Swift 3/4 iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I currently have a UITableViewController that gets populated with a JSON response from the server, all done with Alamofire.

I have my search bar at the top of my TableView, and when I enter a keyword the server responds with the JSON relative to my search. But when I do another search, the previous result of the search still appears.

I would like to know how to clear the previous search from the tableView.

Comment: remove all elements in your array and call reloadData() when search text changes

Comment: while you are getting response from server side after entering some text , that time you can remove all objects from your array .

Comment: Just remove your json array and show some code

Comment: Read this documentation should help you to understand and implement the solution in better way https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment when user changes the text in UISearch bar simply clear the array that you used to show your tableView and reload the tableView. Lets say my array name is `dataSource`

```
extension ViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.dataSource?.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If you want to clear the previous result when user hits search button

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.dataSource?.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Choose whichever suites your need. The basic idea is same. Clear the array and reload thats all :)

Comment: @pablo-colson : I am glad I could help :) Please consider accepting answer as it helped u :)